# PHP Programming with logic and loops (simple help required)

Tags: php

The answer to this problem is SUPPOSED to be 15, but with this code I'm getting 10. My professor told me to check the operator in the loop, but I don't know what that means. ANY help with be appreciated!!

```
function addThemUp($parameter1) {  
    $total=i;
    for ($i=0;$i<$parameter1;$i++) {
    $total=$total+$i;
    };
    return $total;
    };
```

Comment: Did you listen to your professor when he discussed about this?

Comment: sure about this: **$total=i;** ?

Comment: Operator is `*`, `+`, etc. And this `$total=i;` is unnecessary and invalid.

Comment: How could you call this function? i.e what is the value of the parameter you supply? For example: `addThemUp(10);`

Comment: Ugly Eddie, It's an online class, so no my professor did not discusses this. I am basically teaching this to myself...so stop being rude about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function addThemUp($parameter1) {
     $total=0;
     for ($i=0;$i<$parameter1;$i++) {
          $total++;
     }
     return $total;
 }
```

This should work fine.

Btw, when you wrote

```
 $total=i;
```

i is not defined.
Also, don't add a semicolon after functions/for loops ;)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your initial `$total = i` is a problem because i has no defined value. I think you want `$total = 0`

I also think your loop should range from 1 to = $paramater1

```
function addThemUp($parameter1) {
   $total=0;
   for ($i=1; $i <= $parameter1; $i++) {
      $total += i;
   };

   return $total;
```

}